# Access SQL Select rows that have value in common with results of condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, where-clause, exists

Let's say I have a simple table, with the following format:

```
==================================
| ID | Invoice | Box | Delivered |
==================================
|  1 |   AA11  |  1  |   True    |
----------------------------------
|  2 |   AA11  |  2  |   False   |
----------------------------------    
|  3 |   AA22  |  1  |   False   |
----------------------------------
|  4 |   AA33  |  1  |   False   |
----------------------------------    
|  5 |   AA44  |  1  |   True    |
----------------------------------
```

ID is a unique integer, Invoice is a TEXT field, Box is an Integer, and Delivered being a boolean (or BIT, as it's know in Access).

A query like this gets a list of everything that has been delivered:

```
SELECT * FROM Deliveries WHERE Delivered = True
```

However, each invoice can have multiple boxes (as is the case with invoice 1111), and sometimes not all the boxes are delivered at the same time. If a box has been delivered, I would like to be able to get the status of the other boxes with the same invoice number.

I know I can run multiple queries to do this. The one I mentioned above, and then another which loops through all the return results, and then runs another select with Invoice = ####.

Is there a way to do this all in a single query? I think it might be WHERE EXISTS, but I can't find out how to structure the query.

Ideally, I want the rows returned for a single query of the above able to be rows with ID's: 1, 2, and 5. This is the output I am looking for:

```
==================================
| ID | Invoice | Box | Delivered |
==================================
|  1 |   1111  |  1  |   True    |
----------------------------------
|  2 |   1111  |  2  |   False   |
----------------------------------    
|  5 |   4444  |  1  |   True    |
----------------------------------
```

So that even though Delivered = False for ID 2, it is still returned because another item with the same invoice number has Delivered = True

When trying out some queries I got the error

> Cannot join on memo, ole or hyperlink Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want something like this

```
select * from invoice where invoice in (SELECT invoice FROM invoice WHERE Delivered = 'True')
```

With the nested query your selecting an outputting the invoice numbers for reference in the parent query. Here the output of the nested query is used to *'filter'* the results.

You already got it to work, but here is the another way, without changing the table.

```
SELECT invoice.ID, invoice.Invoice, invoice.Box, invoice.Delivered, invoice_1.Delivered AS Expr1
FROM invoice, invoice AS invoice_1
WHERE (((invoice.Invoice)=[invoice_1].[Invoice]) AND (([invoice_1].[Delivered])=Yes));
```

You can test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/369724/4).

For those getting into the same problem there is an explanation and a solution [here](http://improvingsoftware.com/2011/03/15/how-to-join-on-memo-fields-in-microsoft-access/)

Comment: I had something similar to that, but I get an error message when I run it: Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery 'invoices'. I'm using an Access JET Database

Comment: In my actual project, the Invoice field in my table is a text field not an integer (it has to be, some invoices have letters in them). It seems Access doesn't like these to be in subqueries. Any ideas?

Comment: in that case you have to use 'like' not in

Comment: could you update your dataset accordingly, but first could you try it out with the link I provided, just to see if I'm on the right track

Comment: The link you provided gives the perfect answer, exactly what I'm looking for. I changed the IN to LIKE, and I get the same error. I updated the dataset in the original question. I tried to simplify the question by just using it as an integer, I didn't think it would matter (but it clearly does).

Comment: check out at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22573/1, It works, I will now translate it to ms access

Comment: I switched my Invoice column to a VARCHAR column, and it allows me to run your original solution. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95977/discussion-between-davejal-and-user1159415).

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I messed up the Access syntax:

```
select id
from T
group by id
having sum(iif(Delivered, 1, 0) < count(*)
```

Call the above query IC (incomplete). You may want to see all the undelivered data along with the ids:

```
select * from T
where id in (<IC>) and Delivered = false
```

Comment: this is nice, but could you also add all the other fields? Right now you're only outputting the id field